# QML MediaPlayer, Raspberry Pi 4. gst_alsa_device_new: assertion 'caps' failed error

Tags: qml, video-streaming, gstreamer, raspberry-pi4, qt6

I've tested a video streaming from host, I can receive video successfully on RPi, but only in terminal.
If I launch a Qt app with Media Player it receives but it's broken screen is blinking with only black image, in console I have this strings:
`gst_alsa_device_new: assertion 'caps' failed`

In Media Player I enter only address to video

```
import QtQuick
import QtMultimedia

Item
{
    id: root

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        player.play();
    }

    MediaPlayer
    {
        id: player

        source: "udp://192.168.0.152:10001"
        videoOutput: video
    }

    VideoOutput
    {
        id: video

        anchors.fill: parent
        fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
    }
}
```

I've discovered that it's only a problem with Qt. Do I need to reinstall it from the ground up or check for Gstreamer libs, but I've already checked it?

Qt version - 6.3.2, builded for RPi from sources via cross-compiling

It's all working normally on x86

Comment: This code snippet cannot be right. The "videoOutput" property does not have a space in its name.

Comment: How did you determine that it's  only a problem with Qt? Did you try to install a Qt-based media software and see if that works?

Comment: @StephenQuan yeah, sorry, I forgot to add it, but it's not a reason

Comment: @Mitja Well, I've checked a video streaming via console and I get an image successfully. Also, video streaming in Qt on x86 machine is working too. On RPi I thought that it's maybe a problem with OS and I've changed it from RPi OS to Ubuntu but I have the same problem. Later I will check a CMakeConfiguration log, maybe I lost something on configuring Qt build on RPi.

Comment: Later I'll make a test project and introduce all data I have